# C++ template argument deduction for pointers to overloaded member function

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I'm currently working on a template function that deals with pointers to member functions. It originally looked like this:

```
template <typename C, typename RT, typename... P>
auto CreateTestSuite(RT(C::* pFunc)(P...))
{...}
```

However, I soon found that if I try to pass to it a pointer to a const member function, the template will not recognize this. So I then added this overloaded version:

```
template <typename C, typename RT, typename... P>
auto CreateTestSuite(RT(C::* pFunc)(P...) const)
{...}
```

For two different member functions with const and non-const respectively, it works fine. However, if I try to call `CreateTestSuite` for a pointer to an overloaded member function, a problem arises.

For example, assume I have the following class A:

```
class A
{
public:
    return_type test(...) {...}
    return_type test(...) const {...}
};
```

And now when I try to make the function call

```
CreateTestSuite(&A::test);
```

The compiler will not be able to tell which overloaded version I am using. In addition, this problem cannot be solved by explicitly specifying the template arguments, because they are the same for the overloaded versions of `CreateTestSuite`.

How do I explicitly select from the two versions?

**Edit:**
I can accept minor modification to `CreateTestSuite`.

Many thanks.

Comment: With casting `CreateTestSuite( static_cast<return_type (A::*)(...) /*const*/>(&A::test) );`

Comment: @rafix07 thanks for the suggestion. But it's not very satisfactory to me. If the parameter list of A::test is very long, then I'll have to write a lot.

Comment: I'm afraid there is not other way other than casting. Could you please explain how, as a human, you would like to distinguish what is written here `CreateTestSuite(&A::test)`? What overload would you expect?

Comment: sorry, maybe my description for the question is not very clear. I can accept minor modification to ```CreateTestSuite```.

Comment: Can't you use `std::function`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your issue is just to select the right overload,
you might write helpers:

```
template <typename C, typename RT, typename... P>
constexpr auto non_const_overload(RT (C::*pFunc)(P...)) { return pFunc; }

template <typename C, typename RT, typename... P>
constexpr auto const_overload(RT (C::*pFunc)(P...) const) { return pFunc; }
```

With usage

```
CreateTestSuite(non_const_overload(&A::test));
CreateTestSuite(const_overload(&A::test));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e48r41MhT)

*Note*: You might need 24 helpers to handle all combinations with `volatile`, reference to this and C-ellipsis.

or MACRO (with c++20 lambda immediate-called):

```
#define OVERLOAD(name, /*qualifiers*/...) []<typename C, typename RT, typename... P>(RT (C::*pFunc)(P...) __VA_ARGS__){ return pFunc; }(name)
```

```
CreateTestSuite(OVERLOAD(&A::test)); /*no const*/
CreateTestSuite(OVERLOAD(&A::test,)); /*no const*/
CreateTestSuite(OVERLOAD(&A::test, const));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/58vrWE9cW)

Comment: @Const: I have to wait the other users: Volatile,  Cellipsis, ... ;-)

Comment: @Const: MACRO with immediate-called lambda might do the job (example added), but I prefer to avoid MACROs in general.

Answer (score 6):

You can add an additional template `bool` to `CreateTestSuite()` to decide whether to choose `const`-qualified member functions:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool IsConst = false, typename C, typename RT, typename... P>
auto CreateTestSuite(RT(C::* pFunc)(P...), std::enable_if_t<!IsConst>* = nullptr)
{ }

template <bool IsConst, typename C, typename RT, typename... P>
auto CreateTestSuite(RT(C::* pFunc)(P...) const, std::enable_if_t<IsConst>* = nullptr)
{ }
```

Then you can explicitly specify `IsConst` to call `CreateTestSuite()`:

```
CreateTestSuite(&A::test);
CreateTestSuite<true>(&A::test);
CreateTestSuite<false>(&A::test);
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/Y449z3rjh)